# why TS Generic Type will run twice according to the code below?

Tags: typescript

We can see the difference through the results from each example, how the 'Generic Type' works and what the different between using 'extends' separately?

```
type NameOrId<T> = T extends number ? 'add' : 'plus';
type foo = string | number;

type x = NameOrId<foo>
// x is 'add' | 'plus'

type bar = foo extends number ? 'add' : 'plus'
// bar is 'plus'

type zoo = foo extends number | string ? 'add' : 'plus'
// zoo is 'add'
```

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is [described](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in the TypeScript documentation of [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

> When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type.

It also explains how to prevent the distribution:

> Typically, distributivity is the desired behavior. To avoid that behavior, you can surround each side of the extends keyword with square brackets.

And it works as described:

```js
// Wrap T in square brackets to avoid the condition being distributed on the members of the union type
type NameOrId<T> = [T] extends number ? 'add' : 'plus';

type y = NameOrId<foo>;
// y is 'plus'
```

Check it [online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgWwgeQE4EkAmAeAKgPigF4pcoIAPYCAO0wGcoaBXBAIwlSgH4oByOJkx8oALn5gANs3p8A3AFgAUKEhQAZgHtNxKPWCoAljQDmUAD5NWHVIqXLV0CrvhI0WbFs35lAel9QzoaMAkIilnxSMnzKDuDQbHBcJF7kVLQMVuycPPyCwmIS0rJ+AYlcwUXRsSrxUABe2rqplNR0jCzZXJb6Rqa5oQXikcUxSv4NTZWDYzX+pVAA6qhwYKRQxnoAjsxJCSsAxgDWEMCMwDpwAG6ahphQwAAW0AeadIbAhm9QHMZmmMEDIY2MxqPdvk9oEguoxNOoHs8oMwaF8aA94nE1K4UBhMAAmPCEEgAbVwAF00m1Mp0bAN8iJhlFZHZMdAQC5EDisASvPg7BN2dMmWMgA).